# C# Async ApiController Closing OutputStream Prematurely

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

The problem today is that when using WebApi 2 and an Async ApiController - based Get method, that is returning the contents of a file.  When I change the Get method to synchronous, it works just fine, but as soon as I convert it back to async, it closes the stream prematurely. (Fiddler reports the connection was aborted)  The working Synchronous code is:

```
 public void Get(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = logic.GetFileInfoSync(id);
            HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.Clear();
            response.ClearContent();
            response.Buffer = true;
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileInfo.Node.Name + fileInfo.Ext + "\"");
            response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.SizeInBytes.ToString());
            response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            logic.GetDownloadStreamSync(id, response.OutputStream);
            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            //HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
             response.End();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And the GetDownloadStreamSync is as follows:

```
public async Task GetDownloadStream(string fileIdentifier, Stream streamToCopyTo)
{
    string filePath = Path.Combine(fileIdentifierFolder, fileIdentifier);
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, BufferSize, false))
    {
        fs.CopyTo(streamToCopyTo);
    }
 }
```

--------Async Code ----------

The Async version is exact same except:

```
public async Task Get(int id)
{
    FileInfo fileInfo = await logic.GetFileInfoSync(id); // database opp
            HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.Clear();
            response.ClearContent();
            response.Buffer = true;
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileInfo.Node.Name + fileInfo.Ext + "\"");
            response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.SizeInBytes.ToString());
            response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            await logic.GetDownloadStreamSync(id, response.OutputStream); 
                           //database opp + file I/O
            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
             //HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
             response.End();
}
```

With the async implementation of GetDownloadStream as follows: (streamToCopyTo is the OutputStream from the response.OutputStream)

```
    public async Task GetDownloadStream(string fileIdentifier, Stream streamToCopyTo)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, BufferSize, true))
    {
        await fs.CopyToAsync(streamToCopyTo);
    }
}
```

We are trying to embrace the async/await pattern from front to back, so hopefully someone is aware of why this would be failing?  I have also tried not calling Response.End(), Response.Flush(), and HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest().  Also, in response to the questions/comments below, I have placed a breakpoint on the response.End() with the result of it not being hit to GetDownloadStream method has completed. Perhaps the OutputStream is not async?  Any ideas are welcome!
Thanks

**************************  Final Solution   ***************************

Big thanks to everyone who commented, and especially to @Noseratio for his suggestion on the FileOptions.DeleteOnClose.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(long id)
{
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        Node node = await logic.GetFileInfoForNodeAsync(id);

        result.Content = new StreamContent(await logic.GetDownloadStreamAsync(id));
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = node.Name + node.FileInfo.Extension
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = node.FileInfo.SizeInBytes;
        return result
}
```

With the GetDownloadStreamAsync looking like this:

```
 FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, BufferSize, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose | FileOptions.Asynchronous);
```

I left out that I was also decrypting the file stream on the fly, and this does work, so for those interested...

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, BufferSize, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose | FileOptions.Asynchronous);
RijndaelManaged rm = new RijndaelManaged();
return new CryptoStream(fs, GetDecryptor(rm, password), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
```

Comment: Here is what MSDN's explanation is: "An await expression does not block the thread on which it is executing. Instead, it causes the compiler to sign up the rest of the async method as a continuation on the awaited task. Control then returns to the caller of the async method. When the task completes, it invokes its continuation, and execution of the async method resumes where it left off.
An await expression can occur only in the body of an immediately enclosing method, lambda expression, or anonymous method that is marked by an async modifier. Elsewhere, it is interpreted as an identifier. "

Comment: What is signature of the method in async case? (I assume `Task Get...`, but it better be sure).

Comment: In case you miss something in your question, Can you post the full async version?

Comment: I have edited with the additional pieces of code.

Comment: Why do you have to specify the content length yourself? It seems odd you have to do so much work to do something simple like this. What happens what you just copy the stream? Your async stuff us sound.

Comment: @aldertjan Setting the content length myself is a side-effect of using response.End(); which was the only way to get the browser to pop the download dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd take to have a complete repro case to answer your exact question, but I don't think you need `async/await` here at all. I also think you should avoid using `HttpContext.Current.Response` directly where possible, especially in asynchronous WebAPI controller methods.

In this particular case, you could use `HttpResponseMessage`:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    FileInfo fileInfo = logic.GetFileInfoSync(id);

    FileStream fs = new FileStream(
        filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, BufferSize, false);

    result.Content = new StreamContent(fs);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = 
        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = 
        new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") 
        {
            FileName = fileInfo.Node.Name + fileInfo.Ext
        };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = fileInfo.SizeInBytes;

    return result;
}
```

There is no explicit asynchrony here, so the method is not `async`. If however you still need to introduce some `await`, the method would like like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(int id)
{
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    // ...
    await fs.CopyToAsync(streamToCopyTo)
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Question about the first solution, does it leave the FileStream open?  My solution above has a nice using statement around it to ensure that it is closed and disposed of properly, whereas in the first solution I'm slightly concerned about the FileStream being left open, is this true?  I'm trying to wrap the FileStream in a using and delete the file off the local drive once the file has been downloaded if that makes more sense?

Comment: @TChadwick, no it won't be left open, the WebAPI runtime will call `Close` on the stream once it's done with it. If you need to delete it at that point, simply use `FileOptions.DeleteOnClose | FileOptions.Asynchronous` as the last parameter to `new FileStream`.

Comment: @TChadwick, so have you got this approach working, eventually?

Comment: I did get it to work and the final implementation is in my most recent edit of the post.  Look under the *****Final Solution***** part, and thank you for the FileOptions.DeleteOnClose, it was the magic sauce that allowed what I had in mind to work. :D

Answer (score 1):

The root of your problem actually lies in the use of `Response.End()`. When you run Async, it will execute the `Response.End()` before it is done streaming the file contents. This is not seen when using the Sync version because `Response.End()` does not get called until after it is done streaming the file contents.

`Response.End()` is an EXCEPTIONALLY bad way to say you're done processing as it throws a TreadAbortException. Instead, you should be using `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()`

See this article for more info [Response.End, Response.Close, and How Customer Feedback Helps Us Improve MSDN Documentation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/05/25/response-end-response-close-and-how-customer-feedback-helps-us-improve-msdn-documentation.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your response Matthew. With or without Response.End(), the issue is the same, I have also tried the CompleteRequest() as well.

Comment: @TChadwick, this is a content helper I wrote recently to help stream files to the client through the HTTP Response. http://pastebin.com/5B29Pgdp It's not async, but it should work in an async context. Try it out and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you again for your responses, I have dug further into this, and when I run these same calls in Sync, they work fine.  I found that calling CompleteRequest() actually changed the response code to 204 (No Content) instead of 200 causing the browser not to download the file, and that I had to call Response.End() to get it to return a 200 code and have it work.  I want to embrace reading the file async and writing it to the OutputStream in async, but it seems to be unrealistic at this point...